# Loop back to program after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

```
public void runMenu() {

  int x = 1;
  Scanner Option = new Scanner (System.in);
  int Choice = 0; 

  do {  
    try {
      System.out.println("Choose Option");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("1: Create Account");
      System.out.println("2: Check Account");
      System.out.println("3: Take Action");
      System.out.println("4: Exit");

      System.out.println("Please choose");
      Choice = Option.nextInt();  

      switch (Choice) { //used switch statement instead of If else because more effective
        case 1:    
          CreateAccount();
          break;   //breaks iteration
        case 2:     
          selectAccount();
          break;
        case 3:
          Menu();
          int choice = UserInput();
          performAction(choice);
          break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println("Thanks for using the application"); 
          System.exit(0);       
        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
          throw new Exception();  
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Enter Correct Input");
      return;  
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

I am trying to make it when users enter incorrect input type like a letter , the exception is caught and then returns back to the menus, right now it catches the exception but it doesnt stop running I have to force stop the program. So I added a return but that just displays the exception error and stops, how can I make it return back to the menus?

Comment: Instead of the `return;` do `Option.nextLine();`...this will eat up the `\n` character so it is ready for input again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're returning from the method itself in the catch block.
And Do not throw exceptions like that. Just use some boolean to know if the choice is valid and loop until the choice is entered correctly.Prefer not to use while(true), instead rely on a boolean flag everytime like below,

```java
public void runMenu() {
    int x = 1;
    Scanner Option = new Scanner (System.in);
    int Choice = 0; 
    boolean isValidChoice = false;
    do{  
       isValidChoice = false;
       Choice = 0; 
       System.out.println("Choose Option");
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("1: Create Account");
       System.out.println("2: Check Account");
       System.out.println("3: Take Action");
       System.out.println("4: Exit");
       System.out.println("Please choose");
       if(Option.hasNextInt()){
           Choice= Option.nextInt(); 
           isValidChoice = true;
       }
       switch (Choice)
       {
           case 1:
               CreateAccount();
               break; 
           case 2: 
               selectAccount();
               break;
           case 3:
               Menu();
               int choice = UserInput();
               performAction(choice);
               break;
           case 4:
               System.out.println("Thanks for using the application"); 
               System.exit(0);
           default:
                isValidChoice = false;    //if invalid choice, then set flag to loop
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
       }
    } while (!isValidChoice);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesnt take into consideration the input of a letter. It just ends the program and an error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Move the "try {" after the "System.out.println("Please choose");" line.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove the return in the catch. also just as a tip, you can get rid of the do while and just have a while loop, because the loop is never ending.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Enter Correct Input");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I'm pretty sure this should work:

Create a boolean value outside of while loop that is holds if there was a valid input

```
boolean validInput = true;
```

In default set this value to false (meaning there is an invalid input)

```
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
    validInput = false;
    throw new Exception();
```

Make sure the catch statement is still in the do loop because the throw clause will halt normal execution and transition into exception execution. Next the while tester will test if there was a valid input

```
while(!validInput)
```

Lastly go up to the top of the do loop and set validInput to true. This will make it so that each time you clear the previous incorrect input.

This should work.